# SQL - MAX value doesn't fit with the appropriate values

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to extract data for every user based on last invoice data. Here's the data:

```
CREATE TABLE bite
    (`ACCOUNT` int, `ISSUEDATE` datetime, `REFERENCE` int, 
     `ID` int, `AMOUNT` decimal(10,2))
;

INSERT INTO bite
    (`ACCOUNT`, `ISSUEDATE`, `REFERENCE`, `ID`, `AMOUNT`)
VALUES
    (2947471, '2012-12-31 00:00:00', 0005632765, 11543487, 40.18),
    (2947471, '2016-12-30 00:00:00', 0017945914, 36672073, 34.75),
    (2947471, '2012-11-30 00:00:00', 0005448824, 11001690, 33.69),
    (2947471, '2013-03-31 00:00:00', 0006316596, 12759258, 33.44),
    (2956987, '2015-07-01 00:00:00', 0012754607, 26035486, 26.79),
    (2956987, '2015-12-30 00:00:00', 0014371958, 29254616, 25.14),
    (2947471, '2014-05-31 00:00:00', 0009478470, 19223669, 23.34),
    (2947471, '2013-03-02 00:00:00', 0006177725, 12352924, 21.17),
    (2956987, '2014-05-31 00:00:00', 0009504785, 19223632, 20.24),
    (2947471, '2014-01-31 00:00:00', 0008753563, 17845265, 19.97),
    (2947471, '2013-06-30 00:00:00', 0007174573, 14523560, 19.28),
    (2947471, '2014-06-30 00:00:00', 0010048671, 20171164, 19.22),
    (2947471, '2015-01-31 00:00:00', 0011793537, 23926223, 18.98),
    (2947471, '2014-03-31 00:00:00', 0009215609, 18762696, 18.26),
    (2947471, '2013-11-30 00:00:00', 0008394094, 16600223, 18.14),
    (2947471, '2013-04-30 00:00:00', 0006818798, 13568161, 18.08),
    (2956987, '2015-06-30 00:00:00', 0013061086, 26579781, 18.03),
    (2956987, '2014-10-31 00:00:00', 0010942060, 22376155, 18),
    (2947471, '2013-12-31 00:00:00', 0008440468, 17395187, 18),
    (2947471, '2013-10-31 00:00:00', 0007958174, 16156026, 17.94),
    (2947471, '2013-08-31 00:00:00', 0007585482, 15274737, 17.79),
    (2947471, '2012-11-30 00:00:00', 0005632765, 11543487, 40.18),
    (2947471, '2016-11-30 00:00:00', 0017945914, 36672073, 34.75),
    (2947471, '2012-10-31 00:00:00', 0005448824, 11001690, 33.69),
    (2947471, '2013-02-28 00:00:00', 0006316596, 12759258, 33.44),
    (2956987, '2015-05-31 00:00:00', 0012754607, 26035486, 26.79),
    (2956987, '2015-11-30 00:00:00', 0014371958, 29254616, 25.14)
;
```

And this is the query:

```
select account, max(issuedate) as "LAST INVOICE DATE",
  reference,amount,round(avg(amount),2) as "AVERAGE AMOUNT" 
from bite 
group by account
```

(also available from the fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5280b7/58/0)

You will see that I have everything relating to everything, so to speak, but not the max date or vice versa. I need every record from columns relate to max date value. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Could you also provide a sample of current and desired output? I don't quite get what you want to do.

Comment: @Hexadect Yes, grouped by account number. There are only two distinct account numbers. The output I get can be see on the fiddle site following link. Max date value is correct but amount and everything else isn't related to the row from which max date for every account is coming.

Comment: Do you have a unique field in the table? Can we suppose that `id` is unique?

Comment: @IvoVancāns I've noticed that you deleted your post where you stated that you used someone's answer. In this case the proper procedure is *upvoting* those who helped you, and *accepting* his/her answer. Please be kind to those people who help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get just the data from the last `issuedate` you will need to use the a `subquery` retrieving the `max issuedate`:

```
select account,
       max(issuedate) as "LAST INVOICE DATE",
       amount,
       (select round(avg(b3.amount),2)
          from bite b3
         where b3.account = b.account) as "AVERAGE AMOUNT" 
  from bite b
 where b.issuedate = (select max(b2.issuedate)
                        from bite b2
                       where b2.account = b.account)
 group by account, issuedate
```

Comment: Hey Sorack,
Thanks, it works but I need the amount of last invoice and avg amount for every invoice for each account . Now both of those amounts are somehow the same.

Comment: @IvoVancāns that's because we grouped the result for issuedate, we will need a new `subquery` in order to get the total amount. I'll edit my answer with this `subquery`

Answer (score 0):

I hope that code can help you.

```
with withbite
as(
select row_number()over(partition by account order by issuedate desc) as line,
        account, 
       issuedate,
       reference,
       amount
from bite 
)
select account, 
       issuedate as 'LAST INVOICE DATE',
       reference,
       amount,
       round(avg(amount),2) as 'AVERAGE AMOUNT'
from withbite
where line=1
group by account, 
       issuedate,
       reference,
       amount
```